# Angular JS not redirecting to a new template (ngRoute)

Tags: angularjs, ngroute

I have got my routing set as this:

```
function routing($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/registration.html'
    }).when('/chatroom', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/ChatRoom.html',
        controller: 'mainController'
    });
}

messagingApp.config([
    '$routeProvider',
    '$locationProvider',
    routing
]);
```

When I go localhost:8080/ it successfully loads the registration.html. My registration.html is as follows:

```
<a href="#/chatroom">Click</a>
```

When I click on the a tag above it still only shows registration.html. The url after click a tag becomes `http://localhost:8080/#!/#%2Fchatroom`. I want it to load ChatRoom.html instead when  is clicked. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You didn't inject $locationProvider in function routing.

Comment: Can you try removing the `/` from `<a href="#/chatroom">Click</a>`?

Comment: @31piy Still the same

Comment: Did you try just href="/chatroom" ?

Comment: @Sai I just injected but it's still the same. Do i need to do something with it after injecting?

Comment: @Sreekanth That gives 404 not found.

Comment: @fur866 Can you try making it `<a href="#!/chatroom">Click</a>`?

Comment: @31piy Cool that worked like a charm. Please post this as a proper answer and I'll accept it. What does "!" denote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this in html `<head>` section:

`<base href="/">`

Add this in routes:

`$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);`

In anchoring elements remove `#` before url.

Probably this will solve your proble